# Multiple aggregate functions in HAVING clause

Tags: mysql, sql, count

Due to the nature of my query i have records with counts of 3 that would also fit the criteria of having count of 2 and so on. I was wondering is it possible to query 'having count more than x and less than 7' ? How could I write this. Here is my current code.

```
GROUP BY meetingID
HAVING COUNT( caseID )<4
```

I'd like something like

```
GROUP BY meetingID
HAVING COUNT( caseID )<4 AND >2
```

That way it would only count for exactly 3

Answer (score 112, accepted):

```
GROUP BY meetingID
HAVING COUNT(caseID) < 4 AND COUNT(caseID) > 2
```

Answer (score 11):

There is no need to do two checks, why not just check for count = 3:

```
GROUP BY meetingID
HAVING COUNT(caseID) = 3
```

If you want to use the multiple checks, then you can use:

```
GROUP BY meetingID
HAVING COUNT(caseID) > 2
 AND COUNT(caseID) < 4
```

Answer (score 5):

For your example query, the only possible value greater than 2 and less than 4 is 3, so we simplify:

```
GROUP BY meetingID
HAVING COUNT(caseID) = 3
```

---

In your general case:

```
GROUP BY meetingID
HAVING COUNT(caseID) > x AND COUNT(caseID) < 7
```

Or (possibly easier to read?),

```
GROUP BY meetingID
HAVING COUNT(caseID) BETWEEN x+1 AND 6
```

Answer (score 3):

Here I am writing full query which will clear your all doubts

```
SELECT BillingDate,
       COUNT(*) AS BillingQty,
       SUM(BillingTotal) AS BillingSum
FROM Billings
WHERE BillingDate BETWEEN '2002-05-01' AND '2002-05-31'
GROUP BY BillingDate
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
AND SUM(BillingTotal) > 100
ORDER BY BillingDate DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
HAVING COUNT(caseID) > 2
AND COUNT(caseID) < 4
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select CUSTOMER_CODE,nvl(sum(decode(TRANSACTION_TYPE,'D',AMOUNT)),0)) DEBIT,nvl(sum(DECODE(TRANSACTION_TYPE,'C',AMOUNT)),0)) CREDIT,
nvl(sum(decode(TRANSACTION_TYPE,'D',AMOUNT)),0)) - nvl(sum(DECODE(TRANSACTION_TYPE,'C',AMOUNT)),0)) BALANCE from TRANSACTION   
GROUP BY CUSTOMER_CODE
having nvl(sum(decode(TRANSACTION_TYPE,'D',AMOUNT)),0)) > 0
AND (nvl(sum(decode(TRANSACTION_TYPE,'D',AMOUNT)),0)) - nvl(sum(DECODE(TRANSACTION_TYPE,'C',AMOUNT)),0))) > 0
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]! It's better if you explain what you've done. Could you include that in your answer? Thanks!